# Count from two different columns from same table based on range

Tags: sql

I have a tbale like this:

```
MONTHS  CUST    CATEGORY
10       1          1
20       2          1
10       3         NULL
30       4          1
40       5          NULL
```

I want to count no of cust and no of category based on range.

**For example:**
in range of 10-19, no of cust will be 2, and category will be 1.
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '10-19'
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29'
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49'
            ELSE '50-'
         END,
         COUNT(CUST) AS CUST_COUNT,
         COUNT(CATEGORY) AS CATEGORY_COUNT
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '10-19'
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29'
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
            WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49'
            ELSE '50-'
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

`Group By` can be used as long as grouping expression that would result in the same value for the entire RANGE can be calculated:

```
Select
     (MONTHS - (MONTHS % 10)) As RANGE
   , Count(CUST)              As CUST_COUNT,
   , Count(CATEGORY)          As CATEGORY_COUNT
From
     tbale --< :-)
Group By
     (MONTHS - (MONTHS % 10)); --< Expression that would result in the same value for the entire RANGE
```

Answer (score 1):

Giorgos Betsos' answer adjusted to use a derived table. No need to type that `CASE` expression twice. ANSI SQL compliant (since only columns are allowed in the `GROUP BY` clause.)

```
select MONTHS, COUNT(CUST) AS CUST_COUNT, COUNT(CATEGORY) AS CATEGORY_COUNT
from
(
    SELECT CASE 
                WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '10-19'
                WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29'
                WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
                WHEN MONTHS BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49'
                ELSE '50-'
             END AS MONTHS,
         CUST,
         CATEGORY
    FROM mytable
)
GROUP BY MONTHS
```